# Mudar propriedade de um controle XAML ao alterar valor de uma propriedade na viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Eu tenho uma `Page` com este estilo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<Border Padding="{Binding InnerContentPadding}" >
    <Border>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}" Margin="50 50 50 0" Padding="15 50 15 15" CornerRadius="10" Width="330">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sing Up" FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Blue"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="It's About to get fun" FontSize="20" Foreground="DarkCyan"/>

                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Email}" Style="{StaticResource textboxlogin}" Tag="Loguin"/>
                        <PasswordBox Name="PasswordText" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"  Style="{StaticResource  textboxSenhalogin}" Tag="Senha"/>

                        <Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Next"  />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource TextButton}" Content=" I already have a account" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Eu uso os estilos a partir de um ResourceDictionary, e o estilo do botão laranja é esse.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50 10" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10" />

    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Name="tbLoguin" 
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                   Focusable="False" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                        <Image Source="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/spinner-frame-4.png" Width="40"   Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

                            <Image.Style >
                                <Style TargetType="Image" >
                                    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
                                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <RotateTransform></RotateTransform>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>

                                    <Style.Resources>
                                        <Storyboard x:Key="Spin">
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                        From="0"
                                                        To="360"
                                                        Duration="0:0:2"
                                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </Style.Resources>

                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard Name="SpinStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Spin}" />
                                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SpinStoryboard" />
                                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="LightBlue" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="DarkOrange" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>


                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="pink"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LogisisRunning}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="tbLoguin" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger> 
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

O problema é que quando eu clico no botão ele pode demorar X segundos para executar a tarefa (que no caso coloquei delay de 2 segundos para teste) e preciso que o texto suma e o spinner apareça enquanto a tarefa não for concluída. Ou seja, enquanto não for clicado aparece o texto e quando for clicado aparece o spinner até terminar a ação.

O botão utiliza `Command` na ViewModel para executar a ação. Eu estou usando uma Property de controle `public bool LoginIsRunning { get; set; }` enquanto a ação está ocorrendo o valor dela é `True`.

O que eu eu não estou conseguindo é utilizar essa property para mudar o design no XAML, como posso fazer isso?